# Phing, Xinc or phpUnderControl - which one will last?

Tags: php, phpunit, phing, phpundercontrol, xinc

I am still looking into which one of these tools I should use. When I was poking around I noticed none of them really have any new releases:

```
Xinc
Version 2.0.1 released 02/05/08
Phing
Version 2.3.3 released 12/07/08
phpUnderControl
Version 0.4.4 released 08/09/08
```

Should I choose phpUnderControl because it had the latest release and development will probably be continued? I don't want to have to switch in half a year just because some feature that comes with php 5.3 can't be handled by one of them.

I would need PHP Unit, SVN and Codesniffer support.

Comment: maybe when things are stable the projects don't change much

Answer (score 6):

At work, we asked ourselves about the same question last year, considering our needs are :

- Something quite easy to set up ; a few command lines are OK, if you just have to copy/paste without thinking too much (goal : someone who doesn't know Linux well must be able to install the software)
- Integration of

  - PHPUnit
  - phpDocumentor
  - PHP_CodeSniffer
  - SVN log + automatically build when things are committed
- Ability to handle some rather big projects
- Something "sexy", with graphs and all that, for our clients to see

We chose phpUnderControl. Couple of arguments that I remember :

- pro : quite active project (there where new versions really often)
- con : JAVA ; means harder for PHP developpers to modify / adapt
- half pro : PHPUnit and phpUnderControl are a bit close (same hosting, if I remember well) ; we considered if was a good sign that the project would live ^^
- pro : easy to set up ; even the first time (we were a couple of guys who tried ; generally no problem)
- pro (subjective) : more sexy than xinc

We are now (more than) a year later, and we don't regret our choice... Let hope we'll still feel the same way in another year or two !

Comment: I 2nd everything Pascal said.  Also been using phpUC for more than a year, and continue to choose it for new projects.  However, I also use phing to do the actual building, and phpUC to handle the reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Phing actually looks pretty active ...

http://phing.info/trac/timeline

Comment: actually thing is pretty simple and complete. You can extend it yourself if you want more stuff.

Comment: phing is not a CI, it is a automation tool.

Answer (score 1):

Xinc looks to be a more active than phpUnderControl, which hasn't released for almost a year. But as with everything in life, the future is uncertain, what appears to be stable and active today, may not be so tomorrow.

Comment: Now I'm using xinc too but since there is no step by step tutorial it's a pain to get started...